# What is the correct way to iterate over an indefinitely repeated tf.data Dataset in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

The TF2.0 docs recommend to iterate over a dataset with a python for loop:

```
for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):
    # do training
```

The problem is if the dataset is repeated indefinitely (which makes sense for performance reasons as far as I understand) this loop will never end.

What I'm currently doing is setting a number of epochs and training steps I want to iterate over:

```
train_iter = iter(train_dataset)
for i in range(num_epochs):
    # do some setup
    for step in range(num_batches):
        (x_batch, y_batch) = next(train_iter)
        # do training
    # log metrics
```

What I'm unsure about is whether this will have negative implications on the performance of my training process. Would this make my training run slower or am I preventing Tensorflow from optimizing my code, by running my training like this?
On top of this, setting the number of batches to be processed during an epoch can be a little annoying, since I want to do random augmentations in my data pipeline. So the number of unique samples in my dataset can differ between different training sessions. That's not a big problem though.

I tried to find an answer to this via google, but no luck unfortunately.

Comment: In TF 2.0 you generally wouldn't repeat your dataset indefinitely, instead creating a new iterator each epoch. Did you try this and see a performance drop?

Comment: Ok good to know, thanks! I didn't notice a performance drop specifically regarding this/didn't investigate this further yet. Currently I'm just troubleshooting my data pipeline performance in general and trying to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code,

```
train_iter = iter(train_dataset)
for i in range(num_epochs):
    # do some setup
    for step in range(num_batches):
        (x_batch, y_batch) = next(train_iter)
```

is that each `epoch`, the `model` sees the `batches` in the same order, which is not efficient.

Example output of such a code is shown below:

```
tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(3, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(0, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(8, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(6, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(9, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(7, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(5, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(3, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(0, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(8, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(6, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(9, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(7, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(5, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(3, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(0, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(8, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(6, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(9, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(7, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(5, shape=(), dtype=int64)
```

As seen above, value corresponding to every `Epoch` are the same or in other words, the `Batches` are repeating for every `epoch` (`4, 0, 8, 6, 7` and `3,1,2,9,5` are repeated thrice).

Optimized and efficient way to pass the `batches` in the different order is by using the argument, `reshuffle_each_iteration=True`. Sample code is shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=5, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
iter(dataset)

buffer_size = 10
batch_size = 2

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    dataset_epoch = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    for x, y in dataset_epoch:
      print(x,y)
```

Output of the above code is shown below and it can be observed that None of the Values corresponding to any Batch is repeating:

```
tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(0, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(3, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(7, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(6, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(9, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(5, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(8, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(0, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(5, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(6, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(7, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(9, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(3, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(8, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(5, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(7, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(6, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(8, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(9, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(3, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(0, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int64)
```

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!